# Why does my bootstrap v5 card move on vertical window resize?

Tags: html, css, overlap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

**Problem:**

I am currently working on a website and tried my best using/learning bootstrap and wanted to implement e.g. 3 cards. But once I resized the window vertically all my elements shift upwards and it kind of destroys the look of the site, because they overlap into other elements. I think the problem might be my flex elements but I don't know how to make it work any other way.

---

**Code:**

***Card elements***

```html
    <section class="row container-fluid h-75 justify-content-evenly align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card text-white bg-dark p-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, natus?
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

                                +2 identical cards

    </section>
```

***e.g. my footer***

```html
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center py-5 text-white bg-dark">
        <h1 class="pb-5">Partners:</h1>
        <div class="d-lg-flex justify-content-evenly pb-5">
            <img class="img-fluid w-25" src=".." alt="">
            <img class="img-fluid w-25" src=".." alt="">
        </div>
    </footer>
```

**Images:**

[Overlapping card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKBo.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can make it work by giving the margin-top on footer and to cards also,
try to run this code, if you need it like this:

```
<section class="row container-fluid h-75 justify-content-evenly mx-auto align-items-center">
  <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="card text-white bg-dark p-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Perspiciatis, natus?
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

         +2 more identical cards
</section>
```

footer with mt-5

```
<footer class="container-fluid text-center py-5 mt-5 text-white bg-dark">
  <h1 class="pb-5">Partners:</h1>
  <div class="d-lg-flex justify-content-evenly pb-5">
    <img class="img-fluid w-25" src=".." alt="" />
    <img class="img-fluid w-25" src=".." alt="" />
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Sorry but they still overlap [link](https://imgur.com/a/PgpRNLK)

Comment: have you set position absolute of any of this element ?? if not try adjusting with some margin